# Prediction results in negative values

Tags: machine-learning, keras, regression

I am using a simple neural network to perform multiple regression but the prediction results in negative values for all prediction values that should be 0.

What should I do? Is it okay to change the activation at the output layer from `linear` to `ReLU`?

Comment: Yes. It's perfectly fine. Moreover let your experiments drive your decisions.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you!